# How to use vue object in multiple .vue files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have built a [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/)-scaffolding using Vue CLI GUI by installing [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/)

In my App.vue I import my *Navigation.vue*-component file. Besides that I have a view called *Home.vue* in which I implement another component called *Teams.vue* in which I load some data from a .json file using the fetch API.

I want to use various properties, methods,... contained inside a Vue object that's located inside [teams.js](https://pastebin.com/mvNiMLMN)  in multiple files without needing to copy / paste the code in all my vue files.

```
 let app = new Vue({ ...
```

Adding the file through a [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiJ95.png) tag inside the Navigation renders my app blank.

[project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqMCv.png)

Comment: Can you add some more description about what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can `export` the variable at the end of `teams.js`:

```
export default app;
```

and import it in `Navigation.vue`:

```
import app from "@/teams.js";
```

Comment: You should write the path as ``@/teams.js`` not ``a/teams.js`` if it is in the main directory.

Comment: Yes... my bad, just found out. My app is still blank though :/